# Rails: check presence of nested attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I have the following nested model relationships (all has_many):
Countries < Cities < Streets < Homes

In a show view, how can I check if a particular Country has any homes?

Edit: 
Adding the suggested method of chaining with the map method (first try to map to streets). So far it's not restricting the records

```
<% @countries.each do |country| %>
  <% if country.cities.map(&:streets).any? %>
    ....
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: `country.cities.map(&:streets).flatten.any?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call or `@country.cities.map(&:streets).flatten.map(&:homes).present?` or `@country.cities.map(&:streets).map(&:homes).any?`

```
<% if @country.cities.map(&:streets).flatten.map(&:homes).flatten.any? %>
  Tro-lol-lo yo-lo-puki
<% end %>
```

Also you can wrap this long line into your model method:

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  def any_homes?
    cities.map(&:streets).flatten.map(&:homes).flatten.any?
  end
end
```

Usage

```
<% if @country.any_homes? %>
  Tro-lol-lo yo-lo-puki
<% end %>
```

And of course it looks like a good data structure for refactoring! **It wants to be refactored!**

Comment: Hi. This looks like it should work. However it is not cutting out countries without homes. Each nesting level is linked by a (belongs_to/has_many) connection. I'll put my method in my original post.

Comment: I don't understand you. Also there is a bug in my code. I'm going to fix it now

Comment: Works now. Thanks. I'll go away and google refactoring to see if I can figure out what you mean. Thank you.